# Why am I getting this error Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform while using firestore?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform

> The relevant error-causing widget was
> StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>
> StreamBuilder:file:///D:/EgoPro/Flutter%20Apps/task_app/lib/screens/task_screen.dart:189:13
> this is the error

```
        StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          // <2> Pass `Stream<QuerySnapshot>` to stream
          stream:
              FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('tasks').snapshots(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              // <3> Retrieve `List<DocumentSnapshot>` from snapshot
              final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = snapshot.data!.docs;
              print(documents);
              return ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  children: documents
                      .map(
                        (doc) => Meetingcard(
                            id: doc.get("id"),
                            title: doc.get("title"),
                            description: doc.get("description"),
                            time: TimeOfDay.now()),
                      )
                      .toList());
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text("'It's Error!'");
            } else {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          },
        )
```

Why am i getting this error ?

[This is the image of my documents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CN18Q.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ste39.png)>

Answer (score 0):

`doc.get` will return this error if the specified field does not exists in the document. So one of your fields: `id`, `title`, `description` (or more of these) can't be found in `doc`.

You can add a breakpoint or log and check the result of `doc.data()` inside your `.map((doc)...` to see what does it contain.

(One of the possible ways to handle optional fields is to define a model class, create converter where you handle missing values and assign empty string or other default value, so when you read data from your stream you can use this model, and you don't have to handle missing values there.)

**EDIT:**

Based on the error picture in comment the error seems to be somewhere else, where you assign value to `documents`. `snapshot.data!.docs` has the type `List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?>>` and not `List. Try the following code:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    // <2> Pass `Stream<QuerySnapshot>` to stream
    stream:
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('tasks').snapshots(),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
        // <3> Retrieve `List<DocumentSnapshot>` from snapshot
        return ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            children: snapshot.data!.docs
                .map(
                (DocumentSnapshot doc) => Meetingcard(
                    id: doc.data()!["id"],
                    title: doc.data()!["title"],
                    description: data()!["description"],
                    time: TimeOfDay.now()),
                )
                .toList());
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text("'It's Error!'");
    } else {
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
    },
)
```

Comment: I have these fields in my firestore and I have I have crosschecked also

Comment: Did you check the result of `doc.data()`?

Comment: When i individually access Im getting the values but it is still showing this error

Comment: when i use doc.data() it is showing null check error

Comment: Can you add to your question the entire content of `doc` within the `.map`?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CN18Q.png this are the fields in my documents

Comment: I mean the result of `print(documents)` or even better `print(doc)` when inside the `documents` mapper. Please add it to your question.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ste39.png this is the result and it prints "Instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot'"

Comment: @NavneethS Okay, from the image I think the error is not within the mapper. I will edit my answer shortly, please check it.

Comment: okay , thank you :)